# SystemJs And ES6 Imports For Angular Services

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I've got a pretty serious problem. I'm trying to make steps toward ES6 imports and TypeScript in my Angular 1 application. But with angular injection many ES6 imports go unused. Here is an example:

Service-

```
export class MyService {
 public doStuff() {}
}
```

Controller-

```
import {MyService} from './service';

export class MyController {
  public constructor(private MyService: MyService) {MyService.doStuff();} 
}
```

Note it does not matter if I rename the import using `as`.

The problem here is that the compiler doesn't think the `MyService` import is being used! So the resulting compiled `systemjs` code does not include it-

```
System.register('myController', [], function() { ... });
```

To get around this I could make the methods on `MyService` static and never inject it using angular. Ex:

```
import {MyService} from './service';

export class MyController {
  public constructor() {MyService.doStuff();} 
}
```

But we don't have the time to do that. We are trying to do this refactor in steps, and while that's the ultimate goal, we don't have time for that at the moment.

How do I force `systemjs` to include these?

Answer (score 2):

From the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

> **Import a module for side-effects only**
>
> Though not recommended practice, some modules set up some global state that can be used by other modules. These modules may not have any exports, or the consumer is not interested in any of their exports. To import these modules, use:
>
> `import "./my-module.js";`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this is to register the service with the `angular.service` before application startup. TypeScript is eliding the import because it is only used in type position, not in value position. This is not specific to `"module": "system"`, but applies to all external module targets.

Here is what I have used successfully in a number of production apps

*my-service.ts*

```
export class MyService {
  doStuff() {}
}
```

*my-controller.ts*

```
import {MyService} from './service';

export class MyController {

  static $inject = ['MyService'];

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    myService.doStuff();
  } 
}
```

*my-app.ts*

```
import angular from 'angular';

import {MyController} from './my-controller';
import {MyService} from './my-service';

const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller({ MyController });
app.service({ MyService });

export function bootstrap(target: Document | Element) {
  angular.bootstrap(target, ['app'], { ngStrictDi: true });
}
```

To explain, the service itself needs to be registered with an angular module in order to be injected in the first place, so the elided import is a non issue since the registration code, shown in *my-app.ts*, uses `MyService` in value position when passing it as an argument to `angular.service`.

A nice pattern is to register all of the services that comprise a certain set of functionality in a single place. The logical place to do this is in the file containing the angular module which will hold the services.

Also note the `static $inject = ['MyService'];` this ensures your controller code is minification safe while allowing you to co-locate the DI annotation with the constructor that requires it.

I have found this pattern scales very well.